# Can't load a sprite in Phaser 3 game

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I tried set my path with link from web and path of PC and didn't work, ever display this green square my screen:
[image]

My `game.ejs` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade'
},
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};  
var debug;
var source;
var target = new Phaser.Math.Vector2();
var distanceText;
new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('worm', 'assets/worm.png');
}

function create ()
{
    source = this.physics.add.image(100, 300, 'worm');

    debug = this.add.graphics();

    this.input.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {

        target.x = pointer.x;
        target.y = pointer.y;
        
        this.physics.moveToObject(source, target, 250);

    }, this);

    distanceText = this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click to set target', { fill: '#00ff00' });
}

function update ()
{
    var distance = Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(source.x, source.y, target.x, target.y);

    if (source.body.speed > 0)
    {
        distanceText.setText('Distância: ' + distance);

        if (distance < 4)
        {
            source.body.reset(target.x, target.y);
        }
    }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That's like I said, nothing worked with url or path from my pc, I just want to display my sprite player on screen without that green square and I saw another questions, but nothing offered me a solution, what can I do?

Comment: Press F12 and check what errors you have

Comment: You have provided a relative url`"assets/worm.png"` If your HTML files are not in the root try backing out eg `"../assets/worm.png"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it can't find the image its looking for, which means that either it doesn't exist, or more likely it doesn't exist in the location you've provided.

If you're serving this web page from the root (aka it's visible on `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` than you could try simply adding a `/` in front of the path, as such: `/assets/worm.png`, the leading `/` means it'll search for the asset from the root of your webpage.